# objc How do I get the string object from this Json array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

This is part of an incoming array:

```
variantArray: (
        (
                {
            CardinalDirection = "North-West";
            DirectionVariantId = "DcCi_1445_171_0_0";
            Distance = "2.516606318971459";
            RouteName = "Woodsy";
            Shape =             {
                Points =                 (
                                        {
```

I want to get the value of `DirectionVariantId`

I would normally loop and use

```
NSMutableArray *myString = [variantArray[i] valueForKey:@"DirectionVariantId"];
```

This isn't working and results in an exception when I try to examine the last character in the string:

```
NSString *lastChar = [myString substringFromIndex:[myString length] - 1];
```

This is a new data set for me and I'm missing something..

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json contain two curly bracket means nested array.

Try:

```
NSString *myString=[[[variantArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"DirectionVariantId"];
```

Comment: Bingo. Thanks  a ton Avijit. I have to understand why! Any insights welcome, but I'll take it as solved.

Comment: Welcome David sir keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `[variantArray[i] objectForKey:@"DirectionVariantId"];`

You'd need to convert the object within your incoming array (variantArray[i]) to a NSDictionary but it might already be judging by your original output.

Comment: Thanks for that Derek, but I get the same exception: NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb4f2e77010'